# Refresh image without changing ng-src

Tags: angularjs

I have an image upload form which allows the user to upload a new profile picture. I need the image to refresh after a successful upload (with the same url in ng-src). I tried to append a random value to ng-src to force image reload using $scope.$apply but it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reload image in Angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013128/reload-image-in-angular)

Comment: I don't make http request several times

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved partially. I just added a function that delete the img dom and add it again (i know that's not the perfect solution but it works at all)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use $scope.$apply, ng-src watches for changes so if you set a different value of what it was before it will change the image, check code and jsfiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/twizzlers/oebx8any/1/

```
$scope.current_src = "http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg";

$scope.upload = function(){
    //before upload
    $scope.current_src = "test";
    //after upload
    $scope.current_src = "http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg";
}
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Glad you solved it, sorry I didnt answer. Just didnt have time and forgot some time later..